# Plane is visible despite blend mode set to alpha blend

Tags: materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I'm rendering in EEVEE, the material settings for the leaves are in alpha blend for the blend mode, and I've had this issue with my leaves. In the light the plane is still visible almost like a reflection. Alpha clip has no issues but the look is choppy so that wasn't a preferred option for me.

I'm unsure how to fix this issue.
I have volumetric scatter on in the world settings, shader is a diffuse, transparent and mix as the principled shader had the same results.

Is this just an issue with EEVEE or something else?

[image: Plane for texture is still visible despite transparency]

Comment: What node are you using? Are you using Principled BSDF?

Comment: I'm using a simple diffuse and transparent with a mix node, I got the same results with a principled bsdf before this setup.

Comment: Connect the Alpha from the image into the Fac on the mix node. If that messes it up, swap the Diffuse and Transparent mix nodes in the mix node.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue had to do with Volumetric lighting in the render properties. I had changed the light clamping to 0.050 and now the planes are no longer visible like the picture. The annoying thing is changes in the light or volumetric scatter setup has me needing to adjust the clamp to lower numbers. I decided to use cycles instead, longer render times but this issue is no longer present.